# PHP header function doesn't work when entering the page from Android WebView

Tags: php, android, webview, header

In my Android app I have a WebView that shows a web page that I built using HTML and PHP. In that page, the user should be redirected to another page using `header('Location: file.php');`.

The `header` works well when browsing from Google Chrome or Firefox, but when I'm entering to the page from the WebView in my app, the `header` doesn't work, and it is just staying at the previous page.

Is there any way to activate that `header` when browsing from Android WebView?

This is my WebView code:

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    webView = new WebView(this);

    final Activity activity = this;

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://example.com/example");
    setContentView(webView);
}
```

Comment: i think you have to try this one https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel I don't think that Chrome custom tabs is the right solution for me, because one of my needs is to get URL changes